# WebView directory access denied on device

Tags: swift, ios11, wkwebview

I'm saving html files and assets to a specific folder in the documents directory. The simulator is able to load these assets in a WebView when allowing read access to the parent directory. Running the same code on a real device yields the "Received an unexpected URL from the web process" as if I hadn't granted read access to the directory. I've searched around but haven't found a reason to why the behavior is different on an actual device. We're currently developing on iOS 11

Here's a snippet of what works in the simulator and does not work on a real device. Any help or insight is appreciated.

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
documentsDirectory = URL(fileURLWithPath: paths[0])

presentationView.loadFileURL(presentation, allowingReadAccessTo: documentsDirectory)
```

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering I was able to verify that the read access granted to WKWebView behaves differently on an actual device.

In the simulator, allowing read access to the documents folder gives read access to the subdirectories.

On an actual device, giving read access to the documents folder does not honor subdirectories. Giving read access to the subdirectory solved my problem.

If there's a better workaround then please let me know!